# Unable to run pushed binary

Tags: system-apps

I've pushed executable adb file to /system for using it to connect to other devices, but shell can't execute this file. Why?

```
chiron / # file `which adb`
/system/xbin/adb: ELF executable, 64-bit LSB arm64, dynamic (/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1), BuildID=408e8d3f813fbb95b782db5d56f91bc41b451acb, stripped
chiron / # adb
bash: /system/xbin/adb: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did cross-compilation badly.

As `file` suggests, the dynamic linker for the binary is `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`, which doesn't exist on Android. Android's linker is located at `/system/bin/linker` (32-bit) and `/system/bin/linker64`. You need to specify this path as the dynamic linker when compiling.

You may try symlink-ing the Android dynamic linker to the path revealed by `file`.

Comment: `chiron / # /system/bin/linker64 /system/xbin/adb`
`This is /system/bin/linker64, the helper program for dynamic executables.`

Comment: What do you mean? /system/xbin already in PATH and I cannot link this file somewhere for make it more executable.

Comment: @J.Doe I mean exactly this: `mkdir /lib; ln -s /system/bin/linker64 /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` and then try running your executable.

Comment: @J.Doe The most recommended way is to recompile it, specifying the path to the dynamic linker as `/system/bin/linker64` instead of using the default.